# sort by a value in Pandas column

Tags: python, django, pandas, sorting

I groupby my data as follows in Pandas:

df.groupby(by=['industry', 'country', 'category'])['category'].count()

The DataFrame looks something like this after the groupby:

```
---------------------------------------
 Industry   | Country | category |                      
---------------------------------------
 Oil    |  Portugal   |    0     |  14
                           1     |  4
                          None   |  7
           Germany    |    1     |  27
                           0     |  22
                          None   |  7
           Spain      |    1     |  12
                           0     |  1
---------------------------------------

 Gas    |  Ireland    |    1     |  2
                           0     |  11
                          None   |  1
           Italy      |    0     |  120
                           1     |  33
           Malta      |    1     |  3
                           0     |  4
                          None   |  7
           Turkey     |    0     |  355
                           1     |  44
---------------------------------------
```

However, I would like to sort my data based on the count of a particular Category value. For example, sort it by the count of category value '0' so that the frame looks like below. Please note the sorting based on the count of category '0' (22,14,1) and (355,120,11,4).

```
---------------------------------------
 Industry   | Country | category |                      
---------------------------------------
 Oil    |  Germany   |     1     |  27
                           0     |  22
                          None   |  7
           Portugal   |    0     |  14
                           1     |  4
                          None   |  7
           Spain      |    1     |  12
                           0     |  1
---------------------------------------

 Gas    |  Turkey     |    0     |  355
                           1     |  44
           Italy      |    0     |  120
                           1     |  33
           Ireland    |    1     |  2
                           0     |  11
                          None   |  1
           Malta      |    1     |  3
                           0     |  4
                          None   |  7

---------------------------------------
```

I tried using unstack() like this:

```
df.groupby(by=['industry', 'country', 'category'])['category'].count().unstack()

df.sort_values(by=['0'], ascending=[False])
```

and then tried to sort it by '0' but this donot protect the original grouping and indexing.

Can I solve this using Pandas? Please help. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for what you need:

```
df = df.groupby(by=['industry', 'country', 'category'])['category'].count().reset_index()

df.sort_values(by='category', ascending=True, na_position='Last',inplace=True)
```

Comment: unfortunately, this didnot work. The reset_index() will destroy the original grouping.